# How to tar a set of files?

Tags: linux, tar

I am new to the `tar` command. I have many files in a directory:
`1_1_1.txt`,  `1_1_2.txt`, 
`2_1_1.txt`,  `2_1_2.txt`..

I know there is a command:

```
tar cf file.tar *.txt
```

which will `tar` all the four files into `file.tar`. ButI need to tar `1_1_1.txt` and `1_1_2.txt` into one tar file and `2_1_1.txt` and `2_1_2.txt` into another tar file.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: you use a loop if there is a pattern in file names n lotsof files to be created

Comment: tar xzf will extract a tarball. you mean tar czf, which will create a gzipped tarball: .tar.gz, cf will create .tar

Comment: I didnt try it. Sorry I mean tar czf to create a tar file. Hi Travis, how to use a loop?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To simply create a tarball of these files I would just do:

```
tar cf ones.tar 1_*.txt
tar cf twos.tar 2_*.txt
```

Most likely you want to compress the tarballs, so use the `z` option:

```
tar czf ones.tar.gz 1_*.txt
tar czf twos.tar.gz 2_*.txt
```

View the contents of your tarballs with `tar tf <tarball>`.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply use the below commands

```
tar cf file1.tar 1_1_1.txt 1_1_2.txt

tar cf file2.tar 2_1_1.txt 2_1_2.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.txt" -exec tar -rf test.tar {} \;`

If you want to include all files including subfolders, remove "-maxdepth 1"

you can use patterns like "1_1*.txt"

Comment: this one might work with a lot of file names; contrarily to the other suggestions